# Ruby catching class level 'not implemented' exception

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

This is probably impossible but I'll ask anyway.

I dynamically create CLASS methods from a database table.  I've run out of env var space on AWS.  So I have a table with name/value pairs and dynamically create CLASS.name methods at initialisation.

Is there any way I can trap a call to CLASS.[unknown_name] at CLASS scope rather than at the caller scope?

Comment: *Almost* everything is possible in ruby based on its dynamic nature. That being said I am unclear on your intent. Can you post code or psuedo-code as to what you are looking for?

Comment: Why do you get a "not implemented" exception in the first place? How is an exception related to running out of "env var space"? Calling an undefined method results in a `NoMethodError`. Show some code please, it's unclear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Also, why do you create a class (or its methods) for your database table dynamically when already using Rails? Why not define it in your `db/schema.rb` and use ActiveRecord?

Comment: AWS only allows so much space to define env vars.  I need to define some more values in an env var like style. So I define a new EnvVar table with name and value in.  Then at startup I dynamically create a function for each 'name' row that returns that value.  so  can just call EnvVar.[name] and get the value.  Obviously if I call EnvVar.[undefined name] I get a not implemented error because I didn't create a function with that name :)

The self.method_missing defined below is exactly what I was looking for.  It allows me to handle the problem at Class scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `method_missing` method of the class. There you can run your implementation or call super to raise an exception.

```rb
class MyTest
  def self.method_missing(method, *args)
    if %w(known_method).include? method.to_s
      puts "method: #{method}\nargs: #{args}"
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

MyTest.known_method "test", 123
# method: unknown_method
# args: ["test", 123]
# => nil

MyTest.unknown_method "test", 123
# `method_missing': undefined method `unknown_method' for MyTest:Class (NoMethodError)
```